# Custom checkbox not working on user edit page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a custom checkbox that if checked add a user meta field. But when I check the box and then update the profile the meta data is not added.

Here is my code

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_extra_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_extra_user_fields' );
function my_extra_user_fields( $user ) {

 $check_true = "User Meta" . get_user_meta( $user_id, '_is_post_agent'); ?>
    <h3>Agent Author</h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="agent_author">Agent Author</label></th>
            <td>
               <p> <?php echo $check_true; ?> </p>

                <input type="checkbox" name="agent_author" value="is_author_agent"  <?php if($check_true === 'true') echo 'checked="checked"';?> >

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_my_extra_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_my_extra_user_fields' );

function save_my_extra_user_fields( $user_id ) 
{
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false;}else{


             update_user_meta( $user_id, '_is_post_agent', "true", true );



}



}
```

I am at a loss as to what is going wrong so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any errors in the PHP or wordpress log file?

Comment: no, it is clean thats what if puzzling me

Comment: Manually run error_log("test"); in your PHP script and see if it shows up. If not, figure out your error logging first.